# REST Framework: how to serialize objects?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a ListView with a array of nested objects. Here what I've tried so far:

**rest.py**

```
class GroupDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = (
            'id',
            'num',
            'students',
        )

@permission_classes((permissions.IsAdminUser,))
class GroupDetailView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = GroupDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.all()
```

**models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Offices)
    num = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def students(self):
        from pupils.models import Pupils
        return Pupils.objects.filter(group=self)
```

But it returns a type error:

> `<Pupils: John Doe> is not JSON serializable`

I guess I need to use another serializer on my `students` field, but how?

Comment: doest it has any datetime field? Can you paste exact traceback logs?

Comment: besides @roshan 's comments, you can also checkout how nested serializers can be added: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

Comment: The error is occuring because your `Pupils` model is not JSON serializable. You can `import json` and then `return json.dumps(Pupils.objects.filter(group=self))` for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because your model is not json serializable.

you can see @yuwang comment to follow nested serializer http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

or for now, particular for this case you can change your code to:

```
@property
def students(self):
    from pupils.models import Pupils
    return list(Pupils.objects.filter(group=self).values())
```